# Prevent viewing of Checkout Page WooCommerce if no shipping options are available

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to prevent access to the checkout page when there are no shipping options available. I have disabled the "proceed to checkout' button but want to prevent the customer from directly accessing the checkout page. I have tried this snippet which works in terms of preventing the access, however if a customer DOES have a valid shipping option the success message is replaced by the cart page which now of course has nothing in it and informs the customer their cart is empty so they try an re-order again.

Any help gratefully welcome.

```
function prevent_checkout_access_no_shipping() {
// Check that WC is enabled and loaded
if( function_exists( 'is_checkout' ) && is_checkout() ) {
 
    // get shipping packages and their rate counts
    $packages = WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages();
    foreach( $packages as $key => $pkg ) {
        $calculate_shipping = WC()->shipping->calculate_shipping_for_package( $pkg );
        if( empty( $calculate_shipping['rates'] ) ) {
            wp_redirect( esc_url( WC()->cart->get_cart_url() ) );
            exit;
        }
      }
   }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'prevent_checkout_access_no_shipping' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below code. In your code, you redirect after the first empty shipping rate

```
function prevent_checkout_access_no_shipping() {
    // Check that WC is enabled and loaded
    if( function_exists( 'is_checkout' ) && is_checkout() ) {
        
        $packages_valid = 0;
 
        // get shipping packages and their rate counts
        $packages = WC()->cart->get_shipping_packages();
        
        foreach( $packages as $key => $pkg ) {
            
            $calculate_shipping = WC()->shipping->calculate_shipping_for_package( $pkg );
            
            if( !empty( $calculate_shipping['rates'] ) ) {
                $packages_valid++;
            }
            
        }
        
        if (!$packages_valid) {
            wp_redirect( esc_url( WC()->cart->get_cart_url() ) , 302);
        
            exit;
        }
   }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'prevent_checkout_access_no_shipping' );
```